# MySQL joined query with max dates from two tables

Tags: mysql

I got two tables that contain date and time stamps and trying to extract records by the latest date in both.

Table 1 (sessions):

```
id---login_date------------ip
01---2014-01-02 23:58:40---127.0.0.1
03---2014-01-01 13:20:16---127.0.0.1
01---2014-01-01 17:06:15---127.0.0.1
02---2013-12-30 14:34:39---127.0.0.1
```

*also multiple other non-date columns which are not playing part in this solution

Table 2 (reminders):

```
id---last_reminder---------next_reminder
03---2013-12-29 22:50:18---2014-01-07 22:50:18
02---2014-01-01 15:15:15---2014-01-09 15:15:15
02---2013-11-16 08:54:23---2013-11-23 08:54:23
```

Now this is the way I get all the latest logins from the first table for each user ID:

```
SELECT a.id, a.login_date
FROM sessions a
WHERE a.login_date = (
    SELECT max(login_date) as login_date
    FROM sessions
    WHERE id = a.id
    LIMIT 1
    )
GROUP BY a.id
```

What I would like to get is not only the last login date for each user ID, but also the last sent reminder (if any). As this involves selecting two max dates I never get correct results.

Desired Result:

```
id---login_date------------last_reminder---------next_reminder------
01---2014-01-02 23:58:40---NULL------------------NULL---------------
02---2013-12-30 14:34:39---2014-01-01 15:15:15---2014-01-09 15:15:15
03---2014-01-01 13:20:16---2013-12-29 22:50:18---2014-01-07 22:50:18
```

Would anybody please help me out with this.

Thanks,
Simon

////////////////////////UPDATED 2014-01-04 WITH EXTRA COLUMNS////////////////////////////

Based on the request the above table structure was updated to contain extra fields, required to produce correct query results.

*note that next_reminder field will always have a value as it's calculated based on the last reminder value. The query will eventually check whether the next reminder is within certain timeframe too.

P.S. StackOverflow is full of very good answers when only one table contains the date and time stamp (from which I have built what I have got so far), however I could not locate any similar examples that would involve joining two tables and selecting max dates from each.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 2):

if you have only two columns per table, you can directly join it and use `MAX()` to get the latest record for each `ID`.

```
SELECT  a.id, 
        MAX(login_date) latest_login_date, 
        MAX(last_reminder) latest_reminder
FROM    sessions a  
        LEFT JOIN reminders b
            ON a.id = b.id
GROUP   BY a.id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/714d37/2)

Comment: Hi. My tables got more than two columns each. Does that change anything?

Comment: @SimonDau yes, uhmm please update your question with your sample data so i can update the sql statement.

Comment: @今 草 顿 웃 I've updated the original question with the extra information, which should be helpful. Could you please try to update your answer to solve it?